# Particle location more than just x/y/z coordinates?

Tags: node-editor, particles

Using the particle system, I have a certain object being used as hair on another object, with the hair object having a material that changes its colour on the base object based on the hair's position along the x coordinate.

If the base object has a constant slope along the x direction, the colour gradient works fine, but not if the object has parts with differing slopes.  The sections sloped upward seem to be before the horizontal sections in the colour gradient, with the downward sections appearing after the horizontal in the colour gradient.
[image]
[image]

Disconnecting the particle location results in a monochrome colour, so that implies the issue is the x coordinate location information.
[image]

I have been unsuccessfully trying to understand why this is the case.  The results seem to imply the slope or angle of a given section is part of the Particle Info node's location output and not just the Cartesian coordinates.  Is there some way of working around whatever is gong on or to make it so the gradient in the examples is the same?

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining the orientation of your particles in 3D space. Can you post a non-render-view from another angle?